# How to make these ternary operators more readable?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a lot of ternary operators in my code, for instance:
`height: object.isSmall ? 30.0 : 40.0,`

Sometimes even with two ternarys in one:
`color: object.small ? Colors.blue : object.done ? Colors.red : Colors.green`

Since these code snippets are within my 'build Function', it is very hard to read and just does not look right/good.

Is there an elegant way to solve this problem? I thought of 'Maps' but I really do not have a clue to approach this.

Maybe you have an idea. Thank you!

Comment: It'd help if you didn't format it all onto a single line. `dart format` should split it across multiple lines with additional indentation for the nested ternary expression, which would be a big improvement for readability.

Answer (score 0):

You could extract your logic into functions and use proper if-else statements:

```dart
color: _buildColor(),

...

Color _buildColor() {
  if (object.small) {
    return Colors.blue;
  } else if (object.done) {
    return Colors.red;
  } else {
    return Colors.green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if it is more convenient for you, try the switch

```
  switch (object.size) {
    case small:
      return Colors.blue;
      break
    case done:
      return Colors.red;
    default:
      return Colors.green;
  }
```